# Binding TextBlock text not update except Initial

Tags: caliburn.micro, textblock

I'm new on `Caliburn.Micro`.

The Binding a text on `TextBlock`.

The text of `TextBlock` is changed on start up or initialize on `ViewModel`,

But it would not change in fired function.

I don't know why for a day.

I need any help badly.

Here is code what i wrote.

In View

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="72" Foreground="White" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"
    x:Name="DisplayedPhoneNumber"/>
```

In ViewModel

```
    //! Scren Binding.
    public string DisplayedPhoneNumber { get; set; } ="0103214321";
```

When i press a button on view, i call a function like this,

In View

```
<Border  Style="{StaticResource StyleNumberKeyBorder}">
    <Button Content="1" Style="{StaticResource StyleNumberKeyButton}"
        cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action CmdNumberClick(1)]"/>
</Border>
```

In ViewModel, CmdNumberClick function like this...

```
    public void CmdNumberClick(string pressed_number)
    {
        DisplayedPhoneNumber = "plz change...";
    }
```

I check the fired function, and checked DisplayedPhoneNumber  is changed,
But TextBlck was not changed.

Please help.

Comment: Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ok i'll try. thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, U save my hole day!!!

Answer (score 1):

`public string DisplayedPhoneNumber { get; set; }`

needs to be

```
private string _displayedPhoneNumber;
public string DisplayedPhoneNumber{
   get{ return _displayedPhoneNumber;}
   set{
      _displayedPhoneNumber = value;
      NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => DisplayedPhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Associated ViewModel has to inherit `PropertyChangedBase` or a base class that derives `INotifyPropertyChanged`;

Comment: Could use nameof instead of ()=>DisplayedPhoneNumber while using NotifyOfPropertyChange.
NotifyOfPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayedPhoneNumber));

Comment: considering that didn't exist in the framework till recently the syntax of my set is correct for the implementation CM uses.